# Request a connection after the form is opened as in postForm in statemachine

Tags: codenameone

I've shifted to barebone code from statemachine. Here I've code(connectionRequest) inside constructor.Hence connection is called before the new form is opened. What I need is that: after the new form is opened, the connection should be called. In statemachine, if I request a connection in postForm, the form will open and then the connectionRequest is called. How can I do that here?

Home.java

```
public class Home extends Form {
    public Home() {
        Button test = new Button("Test");
        add(test);

        test.addActionListener(e->{
            new Test().show();
        });
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test extends Form{
    public Test(){
        Label nameLabel = new Label("");
        add(nameLabel);

        ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest() {

            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
                Map parser = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
                String name = (String) parser.get("name");
                nameLabel.setText(name);
            }
        };
        cr.setUrl("test.com");
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(cr);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addShowListener` and call the connection request there.